# Unseen discoloration on screen while seen when printed

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing, colors, adobe-acrobat

Once more I return with a wierd case of what is going on. Here is what's going on.

So a user called me about a discoloration of printed stickers and labels. Didn't seem very odd and I thought it was either a Printer Property or Preference setting that was incorrect. So I inspected all the printer settings and test the same file with another printer. Same result but nothing strange in the settings.

Next I tried to see if it's the printer by using a default test print, no issues in regards to discoloration. After this I tried a different file on the same printers. I grabbed a test color print picture from Google and printed it via Paint, everything looked fine here. Later I found a setting inside of Adobe Reader Pro under Advanced Options > Personal (Properties) > Color Management where you can set it from "Color Management of Acrobat" to "Like the source (without color management)".

After this it was working. Or at least I thought it was. The user is happy since it's giving him the result he want but I found something really strange. I send me a picture of those settings to make sure I can add it to my doc only to discover that it is in fact still discolored on my PC now. On his PC the file has the proper colors and on my and my coworker's PCs the colors are wrong but only for the document.

To give you guys an idea, please have a look at this.
[image]
The color on the left is what he has on his screen and what it's supposed to be when printing.
The color on the right is what I have on my screen and what it was printing from his PC.

So you see it's an odd and bizarre phenomenon and I don't know how further analyse this properly. All I know is that it was reported yesterday, the PC was restarted today and it was running since 11 days and the PC is running Windows 10 Pro.

Could this be linked to the color management of Windows?

Comment: You need to communicate a swatch color or other value, especially if you both have a hard-copy swatch book. This is the only way to eliminate calibration as a potential issue. Screenshots between systems cannot be trusted. As far as color calibration: JPG rendering on wide-gamut (10bit "HDR" etc.) is not totally without rendering/gamma/{magic} issues.

Answer (score 1):

Different color renditions on 2 different computers:

Use the Windows 10 Calibrate Display Color function.

Start, Settings, and then enter Calibrate Display Color. Run through the settings, finish off with Clear Type.

Then restart both computers and test.

Also if there are external displays, check Monitor display calibration as well.

Finally, not all external monitors are created equal. View Sonic monitors are excellent and have much deeper and true colors than cheaper monitors like LG.

Calibrate color and monitor display color will likely make 2 computers look similar.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the issue is on my PC. I might have misexplained it but it's just something I spotted via my PC since the picture I send was looking correctly on his PC. Will give it a try still and let you know.

Comment: Tried and it's still the same on his PC.

Comment: Something wrong with the Monitor settings?  Of some damage with Windows 10 Operating System?  Color calibration is very reliable.  Try updating the display driver.

Comment: Will try that maybe tomorrow. The guy using the PC is pretty busy but it could actually be the driver. There are occasional other issues with Dell Optiplex PCs linked to the GPU driver. Long Story short, some maximized Windows are stuck with a white bar at the top and unmaximizing with Windows Key + Arrow Key or restarts usually solve this issue temporarily.

Comment: I also made note that top quality external monitors are better at true color rendition than cheaper monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly solved the issue, however I did the following.

I verified that Night Light was disabled. I toggled it on and off twice to be sure.
I verified the Easy of Access - Color Filters. I enabled the setting, Switched through every option, just to make sure the setting isn't blocked by a cached setting, and disabled the color filter again.
I checked on the bottom right where the message / notification center is to see if there are any odd settings enabled.
I updated the GPU driver and now it seems to be solved.

I'm unsure which of these solved the issue, however the problem is solved now.

Thanks @John for the sugguestions it helped me to find some topics related to this.

Additionally I would like to add this topic which shows a little bit, how it partly would have looked on screenshots from that PC.
[Link to similar issue](https://www.tenforums.com/graphic-cards/140393-print-screen-corrupted-graphic-display-yellow-tint-after-screen-shot.html)